# WPF MVVM: ComboBox height is different for integers

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am working on a WPF application following MVVM. I have two ComboBoxes in the application. One is binded to a list of intergers and other to list of string. The problem is height of comboboxes are different (see picture below). Any idea why heights are different? There is no styling involved on both comboboxes.

[image]

View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" >
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
       <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.OutputLayersAsText}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StringCollection}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.IgzStatAreaSizeText}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding IntegerCollection}" />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _stringCollection;
public ObservableCollection<string> Stringcollection => _stringCollection ?? (_stringCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>
{
     ".igz", ".png+.png", ".jpg+.png"
});

private ObservableCollection<int> _integerCollection;
public ObservableCollection<int> IntegerCollection => _integerCollection ?? (_integerCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>
{
    8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128
});
```

I also tried another combobox with a collection of enums, and its height was similar with integer combobox height.

Comment: You are only showing half of the story here... where is rest of that UI ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada These are the only controls I have in the UI.

Comment: The picture indicates something else

Comment: @NawedNabiZada added full picture.

Comment: Have you retemplated your ComboBox ? If not then there is still something missing.

Comment: Your XAML shows a vertical StackPanel with only two ComboBoxes, while the screenshot shows a horizontal layout with additional Labels or TextBlock. So show us all the relevant parts of your XAML, especially all properties you've set on the ComboBoxes. Presumably you've just messed up some Margins or VerticalAlignment.

Comment: @Clemens Added them. Also added style which is applied to these comboboxes (margin only).

Comment: @Clemens So I disabled style for `TextBlock` and it works fine. But by doing that I will have to put Margin with every `TextBlock` in my UI.

Comment: @Clemens So do you think that this is a bug? Ideally height should be different in both cases (int and string) not only in int case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the default TextBlock Style is also applied to the TextBlocks in the visual tree of the ComboBox. No idea why it only affects those items that display integers, but not those that display strings.

Since you already have a ComboBox Style, you may easily avoid this behaviour by explitly defining an ItemTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```